# firebase deploy doesn't copy or link any of .js scripts in bower_components dir of my Angular app

Tags: angularjs, firebase, bower, firebase-hosting

So I followed the [getting started guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/deploying.html) for deploying a Firebase app with `firebase-tools` and I was able to successfully deploy part of my app. I got the `index.html` and all my .js scripts in the `project_name/app/scripts/**` directories. I can verify this in dev tools. What I don't see loaded is any .js script file located in the `bower_components/` directory which is basically the framework of my app (AngularJS, jQuery, Bootstrap, Firebase, etc.)

Why is this happening?

Screenshot of devtools
[image]

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "firebase": "angfirenews",
  "public": "app",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

Comment: looks like bower is not deploying.. any further steps?

Comment: What does your firebase.json file look like? Does it have any non-standard ignore rules? firebase-tools only deploys the specified directory - it doesn't perform any build steps, so you'd have to ensure that all the relevant files are in that directory

Comment: @Pogrindis there is no deploy/install in Firebase hosting; it stores static assets. s3z, when you answer Chris's questions, you'll have your answer.

Comment: @ChrisRaynor Oh dear. I had no idea that my `bower_components` dir had to be in my `app` dir. The tutorial did not explain that but I guess it makes sense. The problem is that now I have to move my `bower_components` dir to the `app` dir which will then break my local app. Isn't this just bad UX? Or should I just copy my app and make it a firebase deploy-able version by moving `bower_components` dir into `app` dir?

Comment: If your local app doesn't work then deploying it to Firebase Hosting is likely not to work either - it's generally bad practice to have relative links outside your public directory (think of hosting like running a simple http server from your app directory - you can't reference above the root).
My suggestion is to have a build step in your development process that compiles all the files, minifies them as necessary, and produces a distribution folder that can be sent to hosting.

Comment: Ahh ok. Right so I will just use Grunt for this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Create a production version of your app that won't reference the /bower_components directory that is outside of the /app directory.

For complete reasons, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23376737/3957643), it's a better explanation then I can come up with.

So if you're using Yeoman, run `grunt build` to create a separate production ready version of your app in "/dist" that won't require you to upload the bower components directory.

Then use that /dist directory (`firebase init`) and upload it to your firebase hosting.

If you're not using Yeoman or any other generator, you can recreate your index.html and reference to cdn locations of those files manually.  Just an option, not as simple though or complete (yeoman does other things like minify and uglify).

Comment: This isn't necessary and Firebase has no special treatment regarding the bower_components/ directory, unless the user has configured their `firebase.json` deploy file to ignore this. He simply needs to move it into the directory that is being deployed.

Comment: Worked great. First `grunt build`. Then I did `firebase init` in the root directory of my app and responded with `dist` when asked: "Enter the name of your app's public directory."