# Visual Studio 2015 RTM - Where did bower_components go?

Tags: bower, visual-studio-2015

It looks like with Visual Studio 2015 RTM, the bower_components folder is gone and packages are saving directly to the wwwroot/lib/ folder. This would be verified by the fact that the default gulpfile no longer has a function for copying files from bower_components to wwwroot.

However in the default project.json, bower_components is still in the "exclude" property even though the folder no longer exists. Possibly an oversight?

Does anyone know what is going on with this? I didn't see anything about it in the release notes or the bug fixes and known issues articles. Also, I thought the entire point of the wwwroot folder was to house only white-listed files which will be needed by the actual site. Which, I guess there is no ***harm*** in making library code available here, it actually makes our lives easier as we add new libraries, but throughout the beta period the bower_components folder was pretty strictly separated.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-vs.aspx

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025135

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've been trying to adjust my project to match the changes in the latest VS project template for asp.net 5 as well.

From what I can tell, previously there was a task to copy stuff from the bower_components folder into wwwroot/lib

But now that is not needed because they put the bower files directly in wwwroot/lib and this happens because there is a new file in the root of the web app named .bowerrc which has the following content:

```
{
  "directory": "wwwroot/lib"
}
```

so I think bower_components folder is no longer needed
lots of related changes in gruntfile.js as well.

Comment: I think also this is consistent with how other web stacks use bower, that is other non MS things that use bower put the bower_components folder directly in the root of the web site. Myself I'm glad we have a shorter folder name. For my own custom js I'm still using a task to put them under wwwroot, but for libraries I think we don't need to process those with tasks and no point keeping them in more than one place. so put custom js somewhere other than wwwroot/lib

Comment: just found this question which sheds murk on this issue as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376513/are-you-supposed-to-link-to-bower-components-in-production upshot is that many people do link directly to the bower components though often renamed. often people also combine and minify things installed by bower into custom files. I suppose if doing that you would want to leave out the original files in deployment, but you could use a publishExclude for wwwroot/lib if you are doing that while still use them directly in development.

Comment: This helps thanks, I did not notice that .bowerrc folder which did not show up even when I clicked "Show All files", but you're right, it's there in the file system. There are some pretty significant changes to sort through from release candidate to RTM, trying to digest them all.

Comment: even though VS 2015 is RTM there will be more tooling changes to come for ASP.NET 5 as it goes through more betas some of them will have corresponding updated tooling to install. So I figure we will have to keep checking how things change in the VS project templates as we progress through the betas or at least the ones that have corresponding new tooling updates.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that by having a bower_components folder instead of the content being in the wwwroot/lib folder adds more work via gulp. But that translates to more control. I also notice that having a bower_componets folder I get more content like readme, source code, change log, etc... What would be nice is to have an option to do it one way or another. Or just follow the steps below.

By having a bower_components folder I can control minifying, I can control which files are put into the wwwroot/lib folder. I can also control which files I don't want out on the web like .bower.json, LICENSE, or MIT-LICENSE.txt, etc. I can also combine and minify files myself or at least I can control that the *min.js, or min.css files are published only without having the none min files published. Having the bower components published to the wwwroot/lib to me seems as if the wwwroot/lib is more bloated than stream lined.

I did the following

1. Show All Files
2. Right Mouse Click on bower.json | Show in Solution Explore
3. Expanded the bower.json file | edited the .bowerrc file and Changed to:

   ```
   {
        "directory": "bower_components"
   }
   ```
4. Toggle Show All Files to hide files.
5. Right mouse click Dependencies | Restore Packages. This will restore the bower packages into the bower_components folder.
6. Remove wwwroot/lib folder
7. Here is a lean gulp.js that will not copy anything but min files, no map files, no none min files, no license file, etc... For bootstrap this will copy the font files

   ```
   "use strict";

   var gulp = require("gulp"),
       rimraf = require("rimraf")

   var paths = {
       bower: "./bower_components/",
       lib: "./wwwroot/lib/"
   };

   gulp.task('clean', function (callback) {
       rimraf(paths.lib, callback);
   });

   gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
       var bower = {
           "bootstrap": "bootstrap/dist/**/*.{min.js,min.css,ttf,svg,woff,eot}",
           "jquery": "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
           "jquery-validation": "jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js",
           "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"
       };

       for (var destinationDir in bower) {
           gulp.src(paths.bower + bower[destinationDir])
               .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.lib + destinationDir));
       }
   });
   ```

There is more to this, but I think this is a good start. The _Layout.cshtml needs modifying. There also needs to be a gulp task that would create a development version of the lib folder which would have the none min files or include the map files.

One last thing I believe you will need to add this to the project.json file

```
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
```

And this

```
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "npm install", "bower install", "gulp clean", "gulp default" ]
  }
```